# Operations performed on the communications between the server and clients

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

Part of federated learning research is based on operations performed on the communications between the server and clients such as dropping part of the updates (drop some gradients describing a model) exchanged between clients and server or discarding an update from a specific client in a certain communication round. I want to know if such capabilities are supported by Tensorflow-federated (TFF) framework and how they are supported because, from a first look, it seems to me the level of abstraction of TFF API does not allow such operations. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFF's language design intentionally avoids a notion of client *identity*; there is desire to avoid making a "Client X" addressable and discarding its update or sending it different data.

However, there may be a way to run simulations of the type of computations mentioned. TFF does support expressing the following:

- Computations that condition on properties of tensors, for example ignore an update that has `nan` values. One way this could be accomplished would be by writing a `tff.tf_computation` that conditionally zeros out the weight of updates before `tff.federated_mean`. This technique is used in [tff.learning.build_federated_averaing_process()](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/9fd6d3f4315a145c24b20be1078feb0af26878d4/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_averaging.py#L90)
- Simulations that run a different computations on different sets of clients (where a set maybe a single client). Since the reference executor parameterizes clients by the data they posses, a writer of TFF could write two `tff.federated_computation`s, apply them to different simulation data, and combine the results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!