# How to use TFF api's for custom usage?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I have read and studied the TFF [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_federated_algorithms_2) and [APIs](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff) pages precisely. But I am confused in some detail parts.

For example, when I want to **wrap/decorate** a **TF/python** function, use these two below APIs:

```
1. tff.tf_computation()
2. tff.federated_computation()
```

I can not find what are differences between them and when I am allowed to use them. Especially, in case I want to use other algorithms except for **FedAvg** or **FedSgd**. I wonder if you know:

1. How they could be used to manipulate inputs? do they work on *@CLIENT* or *@SERVER*?
2. How I could use them in another usage except for the output of `tff.federated_mean` or `tff.federated_sum` that the value will be in the server?
3. How I am able to have access to the detail of data and metrics in *@CLIENT* and *@SERVER*?
4. Why we should invoke the `tff.tf_computation()` from `tff.federated_computation()`? In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286731/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-mix-tensorflow-and-tensorflow-federated-code), there was not any explanation about them.
5. Do these APIs (e.g. `tff.federated_mean` or `tff.federated_sum`) modify the output elements of each @CLIENT and bring them to the @SERVER?

Could anyone help me to understand intuitive behind the concept?

Comment: Could you please split this question into two? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible rule of thumb about the different function decorators:

- `tff.tf_computation` is for wrapping TF logic. Think *"tensors in, tensors out"*: this should be very similar to the usage of `tf.function`, where the parameters and return values are tensors, or nested structures of tensors. TFF *intrinsics* (e.g. `tff.federated_mean`) cannot be used inside a `tff.tf_computation`, and `tff.tf_computations` cannot call `tff.federated_computations`. The type signature is always on unplaced.
- `tff.federated_computation` should be used to wrap TFF programming abstractions. Think *"tensors here, tensors there"*: Inside this context, a `tff.tf_computation` can be applied to `tff.Value`s and `tff.Value`s can be communicated to other placements using the *intrinsics*. The type signature can accept federated types (i.e. types with placements).

For your list of questions:

1. Both can work on values placed at `CLIENTS` or `SERVER`. For example, `tff.tf_computation` called `my_comp` can be applied to a value `v` with type `int32@CLIENTS` with `tff.federated_map(my_comp, v)`, which will run `my_comp` on each client.
2. [`tff.federated_map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_map) supports applying a computation pointwise (across clients) to data not on the server. You can manipulate the metrics on each client using `tff.federated_map`. TFF isn't intended for separate options on different clients; the abstractions do not support addressing individuals. You may be able to simulate this in Python, see [Operations performed on the communications between the server and clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050014/operations-performed-on-the-communications-between-the-server-and-clients).
3. The values of placed data can be inspected in simulation simply by returning them from a `tff.Computation`, and invoking that computation. The values should be available in the Python environment.
4. `tff.tf_computation`s should be invokable from anywhere, if there is documentation that says otherwise please point to it. I believe what was intended to highlight is that a `tff.federated_computation` may invoke a `tff.tf_computation`, but *not vice versa*.
5. The tutorials ([Federated Learning for Image Classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) and [Federated Learning for Text Generation](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation)) show examples of printing out the metrics in simulation. You may also be interested in the answer to [how to print local outputs in tensorflow federated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334232/how-to-print-local-outputs-in-tensorflow-federated/56334708#56334708)
6. `tff.tf_computations` should be executed directly if desired. This will avoid any of the *federated* part of TFF, and simply delegate to TensorFlow. To apply the computation to federated values and use in combination with federated intrinsics, they must be called inside a `tff.federated_computation`.